# Why is number value equals null value?

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have following teststatement:

```
DECLARE

  CURSOR cur_my_example_old IS
    SELECT meo.*
      FROM my_example_old meo
     ORDER BY meo.example_nr, meo.example_var;

  R_my_example_old        my_example_old%ROWTYPE;
  R_my_example            my_example%ROWTYPE;
  R_my_example_assignment my_example_assignment%ROWTYPE;

  T_example_nr  my_example.muster_nr%TYPE;
  T_example_var my_example.muster_var%TYPE;
BEGIN

  FOR R_my_example_old IN cur_my_example_old LOOP

    BEGIN

      IF my_example_old.example_nr != T_example_nr OR
         my_example_old.example_var != T_example_var THEN

        R_my_example.example_nr          := my_example_old.example_nr;
        R_my_example.example_var         := my_example_old.example_var;

        R_my_example_assignment.example_nr          := my_example_old.example_nr;
        R_my_example_assignment.example_var         := my_example_old.example_var;
        R_my_example_assignment.example_nr_2        := my_example_old.example_nr_2;
        R_my_example_assignment.example_var_2       := my_example_old.example_var_2;

        INSERT INTO my_example VALUES R_my_example;
        INSERT INTO my_example_assignmentVALUES R_my_example_assignment;

      ELSE

        R_my_example_assignment.example_nr     := my_example_old.example_nr;
        R_my_example_assignment.example_var    := my_example_old.example_var;
        R_my_example_assignment.example_nr_2   := my_example_old.example_nr_2;
        R_my_example_assignment.example_var_2  := my_example_old.example_var_2;

        INSERT INTO my_example_assignment VALUES R_my_example_assignment;

      END IF;

      T_example_nr  := my_example_old.example_nr;
      T_example_var := my_example_old.example_var;

    END;

  END LOOP;

END;
```

I want to copy a part from data of my_example_old to my_example and one part to my_example_assignment in cause of new Data Model. It works as expected but **why the if statement:**

```
  IF my_example_old.example_nr != T_example_nr OR
     my_example_old.example_var != T_example_var THEN
```

**is true in first loop???** `T_example_nr` and `T_example_var` are null and `my_example_old.example_nr` is something like 16433 (number(6)) and `my_example_old.example_var` is something like 3 (number(2))!?!?!

I cant understand this behavior! If i initilize `T_example_nr` and `T_example_var` with -1 for example its all fine and not equals.

Someone can explain me why this is handled as described?

Comment: It cannot happen! `number != NULL` is always `false` .. did you add `dbms_output.put_line()` inside the `IF`.. to print it out and confirm if really happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some help in a oracle article. They are writing all comparison with null out of IS NULL or IS NOT NULL will end in status UNKNOWN. Thats why my Statement will go to else if i compare 15000 != null. It is not false and not true!

Comment: `declare 
mu1 number;
mu2 number;
begin
if mu1 != mu2 then
dbms_output.put_line('I Am zero');
else
dbms_output.put_line('I Am NULl');
end if;
end;`